# Characteristic function of the Dirac delta?

Tags: distributions, characteristic-function, dirac-delta

What is the [characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) of the [Dirac delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) function?

Is it $e^{i*0}=1$?

Comment: Your question is already answered in the article you link to.

Comment: @glen_b You are quite correct. Please close the answer if you think is the best.

Comment: I imagine it would be better if it were answered. If one doesn't appear soon I may put one up.

Comment: @Glen_b I will accept it if you post it soon. It doesn't have to be too elaborate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the Dirac delta function has pmf:

$f(x;k_0) = \delta(x-k_0)\,,\quad -\infty<x<\infty,\: -\infty<k_0<\infty$

and cdf

$F(x;k_0)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 1, & \mbox{if }x\ge k_0 \\ 0, & \mbox{if }x<k_0 \end{matrix}\right.$

It is a discrete distribution with all probability at a single point.

Consider the definition of characteristic functions:

$\varphi_X(t) = \operatorname{E}\left[e^{itX}\right] = \int_{\mathbf{R}} e^{itx}\,dF_X(x)$

where the integral may be taken to be a Reimann-Stieltjes integral.

Now $F$ has a jump at $k_0$, so the integral is simply $e^{ik_0t}$.

[Alternatively, if you need a simpler argument, we could just use the definition of expectation for a discrete distribution and arrive at the same result.]

See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution).

You can also investigate the Fourier transform of the Dirac delta function from which the characteristic function immediately follows.

Comment: Thanks. Just an additional comment, this result can also be proved by using the theory of approximate identities and generalized functions.

Comment: An interesting result with respect to Fourier transforms is that the Fourier transform of the Dirac delta has value $1$ regardless of whether the Fourier transform is defined as $$G(\omega) = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-i\omega x}f(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ or as $$H(t) = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-i2\pi t x}f(x)\,\mathrm dx$$